# Simulating ENTER key and export another variable together in Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash

I should put ENTER key value as a shell input to avoid shell waiting for user input.

```
echo 'enter'
read FRUIT

case "$FRUIT" in
   "apple") echo "Apple pie is quite tasty." 
   ;;
   "banana") echo "I like banana nut bread." 
   ;;
   "kiwi") echo "New Zealand is famous for kiwi." 
   ;;
esac

export TEST6=TEST
```

I have learned that 'echo' implicitly has an ENTER value, so tried to run below command to accomplish my requirement.

```
echo | source ~/.bash_profile
```

As I expected, I can see the OS prompt instead of seeing Shell wait the user input.
However, I noticed that the last line exporting TEST6 variable doesn't get exported. I mean I can't find the value of the variable TEST6.

Can you let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is being exported in a subshell run by the pipeline. Use input redirection instead.

```
source ~/.bash_profile <<< ""
```

Any string could be used, since you don't appear to care about the actual value used, but an empty string is the equivalent of what `echo` with no arguments produces. (All here strings implicitly end with a newline.)

If your shell does not support `<<<`, you can use a POSIX-standard here document instead.

```
. ~/some_file <<EOF
EOF
```

Comment: It works great. Very simple solution and it is what I wanted to find. Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, "input redirection" works in other unix such as Solaris,HPUX and AIX?

Comment: It's not related which OS you use, but which shell. `<<<` is not standard, but is supported by several shells such as `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`. I'll add a more standard solution to the answer.

Comment: It(<<<) doesn't work on C shell but EOF works. Can we make EOF work with C shell with just one line command?

Comment: I'm not addressing `csh`, because it's really not suitable for scripting and because this is the first time you've mentioned it. Put it in a new question if you want to know more.